# Convert date to month name & year

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to convert a date to month name and year.

```
$date = '2017-07-00';
$date = date('m/y', strtotime($date));
echo DATE_FORMAT($date, '%M %Y');
```

I am expecting output like

```
July, 2017
```

Here is error i am getting

```
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

Comment: You seem to mix up MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` and PHP `date_format`. Read the docs.

Comment: What does the 0'th of July mean?

Comment: I'd added '00' by concatenate because I am taking only month and year by using input type = "month" & to store it in date format I concatenated. @BartFriederichs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No Need of DATE_FORMAT() function.

**Example-1**: If 00 used in day. Then, output will be **June, 2017**

```
<?php
$date = '2017-07-00';
echo date('F, Y', strtotime($date)); //June, 2017
?>
```

**Example-2**: If 01 or valid day used in day. Then, output will be **July, 2017**

```
<?php
$date = '2017-07-01';
echo date('F, Y', strtotime($date)); //July, 2017
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using correct parameters, use `F` for moth and `Y` for year

Full code:

```
$date = '2017-07-00';
$date = date('F, Y ', strtotime($date));
echo $date;
```

Comment: Yes, its showing 'June, 2017' instead of 'July, 2017'. But 7th month of year is July. Whats went wrong here?

Comment: @NanaPartykar Try `date("F, Y", strtotime($date . " next month"));`

Comment: @NitishKumarDiwakar the day is 0. First day of every month is 1, not 0.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
$date = '2017-07-01';
$date = date('F, Y', strtotime($date));

echo $date;
```

Comment: I have '2017-07-00' in my database. Why should I change that to '2017-07-01'?

Comment: @NitishKumarDiwakar I seriously doubt you have `2017-07-00` in your database, if the database schema is correct and you are using a date column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
echo date('F,Y',strtotime($date));
```