# php - how to print month and year from DB date format

Tags: php

I have date cell in my db:createDate
This is the format Y-m-d. i.e: 2018-10-31

How can i print it on the screen in this format: October 2018

?

I tried this:

```
echo date ("Y-M", $mainIndex['createDate'])
```

Comment: php.net search for date function!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to month name & year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138411/convert-date-to-month-name-year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
echo date ("F Y", strtotime($mainIndex['createDate']));
```

Answer (score -1):

You were very close :)
second parameter should be an integer (time)

```
echo date ("F Y", strtotime($mainIndex['createDate']));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use date format php function something like this

```
echo date_format($mainIndex['createDate'],"F Y");
```

For more you can get it from it [php date_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php)
and for php date parameters [Parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score -1):

you need to convert the time date unix timestamp

```
echo date('F Y', strtotime($mainIndex['createDate']));
```